# How to make MemorySanitizer not stop after one error

Tags: clang, clang++, sanitizer, memory-sanitizer

[Clang's documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html) says that "By default, MemorySanitizer exits on the first detected error."

Does somebody know how to make MemorySanitizer not to stop on errors?
The above sentence suggests that there is a way, but I do not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the `-fsanitize-recover=memory` option should fit.

From [clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html):

> Controls which checks enabled by -fsanitize= flag are non-fatal. If the check is fatal, program will halt after the first error of this kind is detected and error report is printed.

Using`-fsanitize-recover=all` should make all errors non fatal.

There's also some Google documentation about this (search for *continue-after-error*):

https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer

Comment: I actually used this as a linker flag. It turned out I have to use when compiling too.